# JQuery css opacity less than 1.0-e6 becomes 1

Tags: jquery

css({opacity: 9e-7})
followed by
css("opacity")
returns
1

While 9e-6 works fine.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Dr5DS/2/ whose code is

```
    $("#test").css({opacity: 9e-6});
    $("#more-than-one-millionth").text($("#test").css("opacity") + " does roughly equal to 9e-6");
    $("#test").css({opacity: 9e-7});
    $("#less-than-one-millionth").text($("#test").css("opacity") + " does NOT roughly equal to 9e-7");
```

Do I need to specially handle small values? Is this problem unique to 'opacity' or are other attributes a problem as well?

Rather than bring this up on StackOverflow I tried to create a ticket following the instructions at http://bugs.jquery.com/ but got 'TICKET_CREATE privileges are required to perform this operation' after registering.

Comment: Hm, I think it may be browser specific.  In Firefox I see: `9e-7 does NOT roughly equal to 9e-7`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number), the CSS `number` datatype does not permit exponential notation. When `9e-6` is converted to a string it becomes `0.000001`, but `9e-7` stays as `9e-7`. CSS is presumably parsing `opacity: 9e-7` as `opacity: 9` (ignoring everything after the digit), so it becomes fully opaque.

Comment: That make's sense. At least in Chrome when I try `element.style.opacity = 9e-7` it seems to work fine. So maybe I should avoid JQuery's css because it converts to a string and that causes this problem.